# Is there better documentation of Sitecore SIM advanced setting?

Tags: sim

The WIKI on the Sitecore SIM (https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Instance-Manager/wiki/Advanced) is brief. IS there a better explanation somewhere of what these settings do?

Comment: that's interesting question. which level of details are you looking for? from my point of view, they are described detailed enough

Comment: For example: how do I customize the databases - the names, the location, the names of the files themselves? The parameter for this has some tokens to be replaced, but its not clear what those tokens mean.

Comment: if that's the only thing -> `{InstanceName}{ProductName}_{DatabaseRole}`
is MySitecoreSiteNameSitecore8.1revXYZ_master. so, `{InstanceName} = MySitecoreSiteName`; `{ProductName} = Sitecore81revXYZ`; `{DatabaseRole} = master`. Databse locations are set on the sql server, I believe

Comment: I have closed this question as too broad. There is no better documentation, only the wiki you've linked. Posting a "no" as an answer would not benefit the community, and discussing particular SIM settings in the comments would not fit the format of this site. Feel free to post concrete questions about SIM as separate posts.